# com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:8888 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-desktop, spotify-docker-client

[image]I'm using docker Version 2.0.0.0-mac81 (29211) on MAC OS 10.14.6. I'm not able to build the image for my project and get
**Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.10:build (build-ukgr-payment-app) on project ca-payments: Could not build image: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:8888 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]**

Options that I tried -

1. I tired to uninstall the docker and reinstall the same version and latest versions but nothing worked.
2. I also tried looking for solutions in docker forums, but no luck here too. Could anyone please help here.
3. docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 127.0.0.1:1234:1234 bobrik/socat TCP-LISTEN:1234,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock
4. adding DNS in Daemon config

Comment: Can you post the Dockerfile

Comment: is port 8888 free?

Comment: @Adiii Please check the attached screenshot of dockerfile

Comment: @kooskoos yes port 8888 is free